# Filter dictionary string key, list object where object contains propery value

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

Hi i have a this object

```
public class Field 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, List<Field>> fields = new Dictionary<string, List<Field>>();

fields.Add(
     "pippo", 
     new List<Field>() { 
         new Field() { Name = "1" }, 
         new Field() { Name = "2" }, 
         new Field() { Name = "3" } 
});

fields.Add(
     "pluto", 
     new List<Field>() { 
         new Field() { Name = "1" }, 
});

fields.Add(
     "paperino", 
     new List<Field>() { 
         new Field() { Name = "3" } 
});
```

I want to remove from the dictionary all the keys that do not have in the values the string "1" in the name field, as in the example below

```
fields: key "pippo" value { { Name = "1" }, { Name = "2" }, { Name = "3" } }
        key "pluto" value { { Name = "1" }}
```

Comment: That last example, what is that? I ask because you've paired paperino with the list of 3 elements whereas the code above shows that those belong to the pippo key, and what does the example mean? What you want to remove or what you want to keep?

Comment: What did you try already? We´re not here to do your job - which is thinking and trying.

Comment: Your sample code had a mistake (creating lists of `Index` instead of `Fields`). I've changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using linq:

```
var result = fields
    .Where(f => f.Value.Any(x => x.Name == "1"))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Please note this will not change the original dictionary, but return a new dictiorary. If you want to change the original dictionary, just use it instead of `var result` - `fields = fields.Where....`

Comment: Similar to what I would do, though I would probably use `f.Value.Any(x => x.Name == "1")` for the first lambda.

Comment: @DavidG I don't think there's going to be any difference in performance (both FindIndex and Any requires iterating the list) but that's a good suggestion - Any is more readable. Editing my answer.

Comment: Yeah, perf wasn't my concern, just readability. However, it's a pretty low quality question which is why I didn't post an answer, even the example output doesn't match the description given. Better to VTC in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidG I'm sure these are just simple mistakes caused by the fact the OP didn't want to share the actual code. Probably typed it here and didn't bother to check very well. I agree it's not a high quality question but I've seen much worst questions here getting answers and even upvotes, so...

Comment: Well saying there are something is already dirty isn't much of an excuse to add more dirt.

Comment: @DavidG While true, this question, though could and should be written better, wasn't unanswerable, and it did contain (well, almost) a [mcve]. True, there is still a lot of room for improvement, and it *is* a low quality question but I wouldn't categorize it as *very* low quality.

Comment: @Yakumo Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *modify* the existing dictionary, why not find out the keys and then remove them?

```
var keysToRemove = fields
  .Where(pair => !pair.Value.Any(item => item.Name == "1"))
  .Select(pair => pair.Key);

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
  fields.Remove(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Where` call followed by `ToDictionary`:

```
fields = fields.Where(x => x.Value.Any(y => y.Name == "1"))
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```